# Php function, error: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing an error : `mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement` even if i counted all parameters and are equal.

**The function i call for select query:**

```
   public function User_depodit ($Phone_number) {
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT a.Idcustomer_info as             idInfocustomer, a.Amount as currentamountCustInfo, b.Idcustomer_info as    idInfocustomer2, b.IDcustomer , c.IDbank AS DepositIDbank, c.Amount as currentAmountDpsit, c.IDcustomer as IDcustomerDepodit,bnk.IDbank as bankIDbank, d.Card_Id as CardID_cardType ,         d.CardName , e.Amount as VisaAmount, e.Card_number as visaCardNumber, e.Exp_date      as VisaExpDate,e.Security_code as visaSecurityCod, e.Card_Id AS visaCardId from     customer_info a join customer b on a.Idcustomer_info = b.Idcustomer_info join     deposit c on b.IDcustomer =c.IDcustomer join bank bnk on c.IDbank = bnk.IDbank       join cardtype d on bnk.Card_Id= d.Card_Id join visa_info e on d.Card_Id = e.Card_Id where a.Phone_number ='?' ORDER BY a.Created_at DESC ,c.Created_at DESC ,e.Created_at DESC limit 1");
 $stmt->bind_param("iiiiiiiiiiiiiii", $idInfocustomer,    $currentamountCustInfo, $idInfocustomer2, $IDcustomer, $DepositIDbank,    $currentAmountDpsit, $IDcustomerDepodit, $bankIDbank, $CardID_cardType,   $CardName, $VisaAmount, $visaCardNumber, $VisaExpDate, $visaSecurityCod,   $visaCardId);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

            // return user's results
            return $user;     
        }
        else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code failed on you for a few reasons; 1) `where a.Phone_number ='?'` < quotes. 2) not enough placeholders to support the `iiiiiiiiiiiiiii`'s

Comment: You should go (back) to the "official" manuals on prepared statements; it's all in there. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: `User_depodit` that stands to be another typo. You kind of figure that should read as `User_deposit`

Comment: I changed `where a.Phone_number ='?'` to `where a.Phone_number = ?` but error remains. @Fred

Comment: Function name it doesn't seem to be a problem 'cause i changed it to `UserDepodit` and it doesn't help @Fred

Comment: It's because your only parameter in the query is the phone number.  If you want to select only rows that have all of the information currently bound, you need to add them to the `WHERE` clause in your query. Otherwise, the only parameter to bind is the phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistaken to bind wrong parameters, i finally fixed it as follows:

```
 public function UserDepodit ($Phone_number) {

 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT
                         a.Idcustomer_info as idInfocustomer,
                         a.Amount as currentamountCustInfo, 
                         b.Idcustomer_info as idInfocustomer2, 
                         b.IDcustomer , 
                         c.IDbank AS DepositIDbank, 
                         c.Amount as currentAmountDpsit, 
                         c.IDcustomer as IDcustomerDepodit,
                         bnk.IDbank as bankIDbank, 
                         d.Card_Id as CardID_cardType , 
                         d.CardName , 
                         e.Amount as VisaAmount, 
                         e.Card_number as visaCardNumber, 
                         e.Exp_date as VisaExpDate,
                         e.Security_code as visaSecurityCod, 
                         e.Card_Id AS visaCardId

                         from customer_info a 
                         join customer b 
                         on a.Idcustomer_info = b.Idcustomer_info 
                         join deposit c 
                         on b.IDcustomer = c.IDcustomer 
                         join bank bnk 
                         on c.IDbank = bnk.IDbank 
                         join cardtype d 
                         on bnk.Card_Id= d.Card_Id 
                         join visa_info e 
                         on d.Card_Id = e.Card_Id

                         where a.Phone_number = ? 
                         ORDER BY a.Created_at DESC ,
                         c.Created_at DESC ,
                         e.Created_at DESC limit 1");


  $stmt->bind_param("i", $Phone_number);


    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

            // return user's results
            return $user;


        }
        else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```